# Image upload not working in Linkedin V2 API

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api, php-curl

I'm now working with **Linkedin V2** integration with my application. I'm facing an issue while trying to upload image to Linkedin.

I have tried **CURL request** from my terminal(I'm using Ubuntu OS) & getting response as below:

**Terminal command (Working & file uploaded):**

```
curl -i --upload-file /Users/peter/Desktop/superneatimage.png --header "Authorization: Bearer redacted" 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJbrN86Zm265gAAAWemyz2pxPSgONtBiZdchrgG872QltnfYjnMdb2j3A&app=1953784&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2H-IhpbfXrRow1'
```

It's response as below:

> HTTP/2 201  date: Wed Apr 10 09:14:44 UTC 2019 server: Play
>   set-cookie: lang=v=2&lang=en-us; Path=/; Domain=api.linkedin.com
>   x-ambry-creation-time: Wed Apr 10 09:14:44 UTC 2019
>   access-control-allow-origin: https://www.linkedin.com content-length:
>   0

**I'm facing issue** when I integrate the CURL request in my application. My CURL request code from my application is given below.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxx';
$headers[] = 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJbrN86Zm265gAAAWemyz2pxPSgONtBiZdchrgG872QltnfYjnMdb2j3A&app=1953784&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2H-IhpbfXrRow1',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("upload-file" => '/Users/peter/Desktop/superneatimage.png')
    // CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("upload-file" => new CURLFile('/Users/peter/Desktop/superneatimage.png'))
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Response as:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: Play Set-Cookie: lang=v=2&lang=en-us;
>   Path=/; Domain=api.linkedin.com Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2019 09:16:25 GMT
>   Content-Length: 0 X-Li-Fabric: prod-lsg1 Connection: keep-alive

[Link to the Linkedin doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/marketing/context#creating-a-share-on-linkedin)

[Similar question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998990/create-an-image-share-over-linkedin-api-v2-not-working), which do not solved my issue.

Comment: You are not uploading any file, you are sending the file path only. Prefixing the file path with `@` _was_ the way to do file uploads, but that is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0, so what you should be using is https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: I have used `@` before image path as you said but it did not helped me. Used PHP 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **Guzzle HTTP** client instead of curl.I tried curl but it is not working.

First install the composer in the current directory with below command:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

After the composer Update, run below command to install the Guzzle (default version will be 3.9 it requires php >= 5.3.3.You can specify based on your php version):

> php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
>
> Once Guzzle client installed successfully.Please use the below code to upload the file

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client =new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $image_path='/path_to_your_image/my_image.png';
    $result=$client->request('PUT',$target_url, [
             'headers' => [
                 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
              ],
              'body' => fopen($image_path, 'r'),
    
        ]);
```

You will get below success full response

> HTTP/2 201
>
> date: Wed Apr 10 09:14:44 UTC 2019 server: Play set-cookie:
> lang=v=2&lang=en-us; Path=/; Domain=api.linkedin.com
> x-ambry-creation-time: Wed Apr 10 09:14:44 UTC 2019
> access-control-allow-origin: https://www.linkedin.com content-length:
> 0

**Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client** that makes it easy to send HTTP requests and trivial to integrate with web services.

- Simple interface for building query strings, POST requests, streaming large uploads, streaming large downloads, using HTTP cookies, uploading JSON data, etc...
- Can send both synchronous and asynchronous requests using the same interface.
  Uses PSR-7 interfaces for requests, responses, and streams. This allows you to utilize other PSR-7 compatible libraries with Guzzle.
- Abstracts away the underlying HTTP transport, allowing you to write environment and transport agnostic code; i.e., no hard dependency on cURL, PHP streams, sockets, or non-blocking event loops.
- Middleware system allows you to augment and compose client behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will let you know after checking this. How can I install Guzzle in Linux? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Thank you for the details. I have got the response.